# Optimal scaling/sizing of websites in UIWebViews

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, scale

I'm familiar with two approaches for scaling content in UIWebViews that are on the smaller side (>~320 points in width).

The first approach is to set the appropriate frame size on the web view and the scalesPagesToFit property. This works fine but may easily result in content being presented at such a size that it is not easily consumed.

Another approach is to inject JavaScript to set the content's viewPort width programatically. This works on sites that are intended for mobile presentation (eg, responsive web design). If you're presenting a website that was coded for mobile consumption, the results with this are far superior in terms of content legibility than using the scaleToFit property.

The trouble is that these two approaches are mutually exclusive, or so it seems. If you scale the contents of a site that *doesn't* feature responsive design and then inject the JS to set the viewPort, you end up with an illegible content frame that scuttles the good work of  scalesToFit.

Is there any way to detect programmatically, when a page will respond to the javascript injection as expected and optimize the site for the presentation size, versus when the page will not respond to the javascript but injecting it results in the undoing of the auto-scaling?